# Which locking primitive to use?

Tags: .net, multithreading, waithandle

Yesterday i discovered we had a multithreading issue with a simple caching object we use:

```
 If Dictionary.Contains(lsKey.ToLower) Then 'if rate cached, then return value
      lvResult = Dictionary.Item(lsKey.ToLower)

  Else 'else retrieve from database, store, and return value
      lvResult = GetRateFromDB(voADO,
                               veRateType,
                               vdEffDate)
      Dictionary.Add(lsKey.ToLower, lvResult)

  End If
```

We discovered this problem on our asp.net website. The error messaged read something like "your trying to add a value to a hashtable that already exists. As you can tell from the code above the potential definitely exits for this to happen. I was somewhat familiar with waithandles and thought they would solve the problem. So i declared my waithandle at the class level:

```
private Shared _waitHandle as new AutoResetEvent(True)
```

Then in the specific section of code with the problem:

```
_waitHandle.Wait()
If Dictionary.Contains(lsKey.ToLower) Then 'if rate cached, then return value
    lvResult = Dictionary.Item(lsKey.ToLower)

Else 'else retrieve from database, store, and return value
    lvResult = GetRateFromDB(voADO,
                             veRateType,
                             vdEffDate)
     Dictionary.Add(lsKey.ToLower, lvResult)
End If
_waitHandle.Set()
```

for some reason the following code above was ALWAYS blocked. Even the very first thread the accessed the code. I played with things for awhile and even tried to set the waithandle to signaled in the constructor but i never could get it to work.

I end up using the following instead which works fine:

```
SyncLock loLock
    If Dictionary.Contains(lsKey.ToLower) Then 'if rate cached, then return value
        lvResult = Dictionary.Item(lsKey.ToLower)

    Else 'else retrieve from database, store, and return value
        lvResult = GetRateFromDB(voADO,
                                 veRateType,
                                 vdEffDate)
        Dictionary.Add(lsKey.ToLower, lvResult)

    End If
End SyncLock
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why didn't the waithandle solution work?
2. Is SynLock the correct / optimized lock type to use in this case?

Comment: Switching to a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) would be a far more robust solution, if you're on .NET 4 or later.

Comment: If you do switch to a `ConcurrentDictionary`, then you would need to use the `AddOrUpdate()` method. If you just kept the above pattern (`if .Contains(), else .Add()`) you still have a race condition as a thread can add the same key after you've called .Contains().

Comment: Whilst an `AutoResetEvent` is probably not the appropriate locking method to use, the explanations given by the two answers so far do not seem to correctly explain why the `AutoResetEvent` method you tried did not work. One possibility is that an exception was thrown during `GetRateFromDB`, preventing the `_waitHandle.Set()` from being called, and so all threads eventually get blocked on the `Wait()`. Putting the `Set()` in a `Finally` block would likely resolve that (although again, there are better synchronization methods to use than `AutoResetEvent`).

Comment: You should take a look at [Dictionary.TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx). That won't solve your concurrency issue, but it makes your code a little cleaner.

Comment: @Iridium, the `Set` will never get called because the thread is still blocked at the `Wait` (it hasn't gotten there yet).

Comment: @joshpoley - The constructor for `AutoResetEvent` takes a boolean value indicating whether the event should be initially in a signalled state or not. Since the OP is passing `True` for this value, the event *is* initially signalled, and so the first call to `Wait()` will *not* block and should return immediately, clearing the initial signalled state (which would block *subsequent* threads at the `Wait()` until `Set()` is called by the first thread).

Comment: @Iridium, good call, I missed the True parameter to AutoResetEvent.

Answer (score 1):

1 waithandles block until signaled.  You would need something somewhere to signal that waithandle for it to not block the first thread to get access.  I believe it would work if you had signaled the handle in the constructor where you created the waithandle.  Consider it like there is a slot for a signal inside the waithandle any thread that calls wait will wait until it can consume a signal before leaving the wait call.

2  In this case it probably isn't the best lock to use, if two threads try to read a value that is already in the cache then one will be blocked until the other is finished.  I would use a readerwriter lock instead.  This way multiple threads can read the cache at the same time and you can upgrade to write when necessary.

If you don't mind multiple loads of the same value to the cache you could use a concurrentdictionary.  Any thread that needed a value not yet loaded would load it then call tryadd.  In the case where multiple threads try to access the same unloaded value at the same time all of them will do the work of calling GetRateFromDB.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Terms:

- An "**Event**" allows one thread (or process) signal another thread (or process).
- A "**Semaphore**" is similar to an Event but it can be used to signal (wake) a specific number of threads.
- A "**Critical Section**" is used to prevent simultaneous access to a block of code.
- A "**Slim Lock**" is similar to a critical section but typically doesn't allow the thread which owns the lock to enter it multiple times (which is allowed using a critical section).
- A "**Reader Writer**" lock gives you the flexibility to lock an object in exclusive mode (similar to a critical section) or in a shared mode which would allow multiple threads to execute the same block.
- For completeness, there is also a "**Mutex**" which is very similar to a critical section, but can be shared across processes.

So using an `AutoResetEvent` above is definitely not what you want. When a thread calls one of the `Wait` methods it will block until it receives a signal from another thread. Nobody ever signals you, so you wait forever.

The `SyncLock` statement uses a critical section under the covers and prevents any thread from entering the same chunk of code at the same time. This will give you the protection you need. But because **you need to protect all accesses to the Dictionary object to avoid corruption**, you need to use the lock everywhere you use the Dictionary object.

As already stated, the `ConcurrentDictionary` is a good thing to use in this case as it essentially has a highly tuned Reader Writer lock built into it. So then you don't have to go and add a bunch of locks throughout your code base. But as noted in my comment, you can still have race conditions when using a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).